# Override ShippingInformationManagement

Tags: magento2, checkout, totals

I added custom check box field in checkout 1st step below Shipping Methods section.

[image]

how to check `is checked or not` when i click next button,so based on this I  can add custom fee in order totals.

when I click next button its calling rest api `ShippingInformationManagement`.

i think i need to override  `saveAddressInformation` method in `ShippingInformationManagement` class.

Please find below for more details.

https://github.com/sivajik34/Delivery-Signature-Magento2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow the step:

**how to check is checked or not when i click next button,so based on this I can add custom fee in order totals.**

--You need to js saveShippingInformation method by following way.
Create a requirejs-config.js [Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js]

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default': 'vendor_Module/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default'
        }
    }
};
```

Now create default.js[Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js]

Here you need to pass additional param. [Here is an example](https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date/blob/master/SR/DeliveryDate/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js) Check following params

```
extension_attributes:{
                            delivery_date: $('[name="delivery_date"]').val()
                        }
```

Now you can able to pass value to api.

Create **Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml** for pluginize ShippingInformationManagement.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
        <plugin name="sr_save_delivery_date_in_quote" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create **Vendor/Module//Plugin/Checkout/Model/ShippingInformationManagement.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Model;
class ShippingInformationManagement
{
    protected $quoteRepository;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject
     * @param $cartId
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
     */
    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ) {
        $extAttributes = $addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes();
        $deliveryDate = $extAttributes->getDeliveryDate();
    }
}
```

Create **Vendor/Module/etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface">
        <attribute code="delivery_date" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

[You can use this module as an example](https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date/tree/master/SR/DeliveryDate)

Comment: Hy @Sohel I want to add some extra amount to shipping amount for that I've overrided `ShippingInformationManagement` now when I update the shipping amount that is not updated in DB `$quote->setShippingAmount(30)` but still when I log the file then I still see the old prices... did you know anything about this?